# OracleSolaris 11.2 - setting MANPATH variable

Tags: solaris, configuration, environment-variables, opensolaris

What is the right way to extend MANPATH in Solaris? Currently it is empty for a user session, so I get to do it manually in `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
MANPATH=/usr/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/sfw/man:/opt/solarisstudio12.3/man
export MANPATH
```

But is this right? On linux, for instance I could update `/etc/manpath.config` and this would be visible to all users; or `man -w` would help figure out man pages location. I don't know how I could do this on Solaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E24456/userenv-1.html

Looks like we don't really need `MANPATH` at all, simply adjust `PATH` and the `man` commands would do the rest.